# Is it possible to show the same view controller in portrait and in landscape orientation, side by side in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, orientation

One of the known methods of handling device orientation change is having two different top views - one for landscape and one for portrait (only one of them will be visible, depending on the orientation).
I implemented that, and now my storyboard looks terrible (both views shown one on top of the other). It looses the effect of the UI documentation.

Is there an option in Xcode's Interface Builder to display the **same** view controller in portrait and in landscape mode, side by side and for each one of them to tie the appropriate view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not currently possible with Xcode 5 or previous versions.